# Select option width

Tags: css, select, width, html-select

I'm not really experienced in CSS and I have no tools that are best used in designing webpages such as Microsoft expression.

My problem is simple: I want my page to look as symmetrical as possible so I want my select options to be of same width. I've searched and the best solution is to use width="" option on CSS. So how do I go about this?

I have this example:

```html
<tr>
    <td>
        <label for="meal">Meal:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="meal">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Any</option>
            <option value="Breakfast">Breakfast</option>
            <option value="Brunch">Brunch</option>
            <option value="Lunch">Lunch</option>
            <option value="Snack">Snack</option>
            <option value="Dinner">Dinner</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>
        <label for="cooking">Cooking:</label>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="cooking">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">Any</option>
            <option value="Baked">Baked</option>
            <option value="BBQ">Barbecque</option>
            <option value="Boiled">Boiled</option>
            <option value="Dfried">Deep Fried</option>
            <option value="Grilled">Grilled</option>
            <option value="Steamed">Steamed</option>
        </select>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to set the same width on all `select` elements in a document, you can write e.g.

```
<style>
select { width: 5.5em }
</style>
```

in the `head` part. If you wish to do that for some `select` elements only, you need to replace the selector `select` by something more restrictive, e.g. `select.foo` to restrict the effect to those `select` elements that have the `class=foo` attribute.

This is tricky because you need a width that is sufficient for all options, and you probably want to get as close to the maximal width as possible. The widths of options depend on their text *and* on the font. (Using the `px` makes things even worse. Then things would depend on font size, too.)

Consider whether it is necessary to set the widths the same. It is just an esthetic preference, not shared by all people, and it may in fact be bad for usability. A dropdown with short options should perhaps look different from another dropdown that has long options.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put a class on the selects and use

```
<select class="selectList" id="meal"><option>your options</options></select
```

and then added this to your css

```
select.selectList { width: 150px; }
```

Note: label for works with id's and not name and refrain from using inline-style css ().

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akwasin/wszfz7dv/)

Answer (score 0):

For your width setting, you have a small typo. You need

```
<select style="width: 400px">
```

Comment: One more thing, i have a css file so id rather put it in there, how do i link those selects? this is my main question

Comment: @user1891608, you should clarify what you main question is by editing the question itself, not just in comments. Currrenty, it does not mention at all the issue that you here characterize as the main question.

Comment: I think i did, i asked how do i go about... means how do i do this.. what are the ways i can do this... although not specifically.. i forgot to mention that so im sorry :(

Answer (score 0):

In your stylesheet:

```
table tr td select{width:150px;}
```

That will make all the selectboxes inside a table cell the same width. I would not go the inline css route.

Comment: This does not change anything, is there any particular syntax i should know?

Comment: Well this should definitely change the width of your select box. Are you sure you are linking to an external stylesheet properly? Have you had a look at Firebug for firefox? Its a really good tool for checking html and css.